# function variable and in function variable have the same name. How to access?

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, functional-programming, var

I was wondering how does javascript(if possible) access a variable that has the same name as the variable input of the function.

```
function myfunc(var1)
{
    var var1 = "World";
    alert(var1);
}
```

How can I tell the function which var1 to print?

Comment: How about using unique variables names instead? :-3

Comment: Why do you want to use the same name?

Comment: It is a question just for the sake of a question that is why the first comment is irrelevant and I hope I answered the second. The words "I was wondering" were supposed to clarify that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nnnnnn is correct, I tested it. Arguments that are passed to a function can be accessed in 2 ways, by their parameter name and through the `arguments` variable. `arguments[0]` would be the value of the first parameter.

In the example below you would expect 2 alerts, the first one saying `"Hello"` and the second saying `"World"`. But they both say `"World"` proving that assigning `var1` actually changes the value of the argument being passed to the function.

```
function myfunc(var1) {
    var var1 = "World";
    alert(arguments[0]);
    alert(var1);
}

myfunc("Hello");
```

Comment: Actually in strict mode (in JS 1.8.5) the `arguments` object is not supposed to be updated by changes to named parameters, so in strict mode your example should say "Hello" "World", but I deliberately didn't mention that in my answer because I didn't want to muddy the waters or in any way encourage creation of local variables with the same name as function arguments. Also (as of when I last looked into it) some browsers that claimed to support strict mode didn't actually implement this rule.

Comment: @nnnnnn I would like to know how to do that. I am not saying I would. I am curious. Can you please show me?

Comment: nnnnnn is saying that the code sample I provided will work as you expect where you would see an alert that says "Hello" followed by an alert that ways "World" IF you run the JavaScript in strict mode. As far as how you would see it to strict mode you can find more information here: http://goo.gl/DbsKb - as far as what browsers support it and how well they support it you would have to research that, or find out through trial an error.

Comment: @luisperezphd and @@nnnnnn thank you. All my code is written with strict code. As for the compatability you can find this list usful:   http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Answer (score 6):

That doesn't actually define a second variable with the same name. Even with the `var` statement you are just overwriting the function parameter of the same name.

Just give your second variable a unique name.

(By the way, even if this actually worked it would still be a *bad* idea because it would make your code hard to read.)